# Does Perl module Email::MIME->create_html support Reply-to option?

Tags: perl, email

I have been upgrading some Perl sendmail automated emails to take advantage of features with Email::MIME::CreateHTML and Email::Sender notably SMTP authentication.  It works fine.

```
    use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
    use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
    use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;

    my $smtpserver = 'myserver.com';
    my $smtpport = ###;
    my $smtpuser   = 'noreply@mywebsite.com';
    my $smtppassword = 'mypassword';

    my $xport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
      host => $smtpserver,
      port => $smtpport,
      ssl => 'ssl',
      sasl_username => $smtpuser,
      sasl_password => $smtppassword,
    });
    my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
      header => [
        To      => $email_to_recipient,
        From    => $email_from_person,
        Subject => $email_subject_line,
      ],
      body => $email_body_code,
    );
    sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

However, I have not been able to find anywhere in the documents how to add a Reply-to option.  Using sendmail it was as simple as adding another line:

```
    print SENDMAIL "From: noreply\@myserver.com\n"; 
    print SENDMAIL "To: recipient@theirserver.com";
    print SENDMAIL "Reply-to: replyhere@myserver.com\n";
```

Tried to sneak in:

```
    my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
      header => [
        To      => $email_to_recipient,
        From    => $email_from_person,
        Reply-to   => $email_reply_to_person,
        Subject => $email_subject_line,
      ],
      body => $email_body_code,
    );
    sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

but the reply-to part was ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`. That would have given you a pointer to the problem with your code: 'Bareword "Reply" not allowed while "strict subs" in use'

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct, and yes that didn't work.  How does one add a "reply-to" option is my question?

Comment: @DaveLeLacheur: put it into quotes, i.e. `'Reply-to' => ....`.

Comment: Looks awesome Steffen.  Thank you !!!